# Internet Explorer 7+ returns the error "Object expected" although none of the other browsers do

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

Each time I load a page in Internet Explorer 7 or greater I get the error `Object Expected` when calling the function below. The script appears right at the bottom of the page before the closing `</body>` tag. There are no elements with the same `name` or `id`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     window.onload = show();
</script>
```

The Javascript function it is attempting to call is

```
function show() {
    obj1
     = document.getElementById("container").innerHTML
     = '<div style="width: 960px; height: 2000px;"><p>Hello World.<br>Here I am.</p>'
         + '<p><a href="#" onclick="hide();">test</a></p></div>';
}
```

1. Why does this error not appear in any of the other browsers?
2. What do I need to change to resolve the issue?

**EDIT 0**

If I move the function `show` into the same block at `window.onload`, `hide()` now no longer works.

Javascript code

```
function show() {
    obj1
     = document.getElementById("container").innerHTML
     = '<div style="width: 960px; height: 2000px;"><p>Hello World.<br>Here I am.</p>'
         + '<p><a href="#" onclick="hide();">test</a></p></div>';
}

function hide() {   
    obj1 = document.getElementById("container");
    if(obj1){
        alert("Hi");
        obj1.style.display = "none";
        obj1.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }else{
        alert("Cannot find the element with id container.");
    }
}
```

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict/EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtm1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-us" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <meta name="copyright" content="&copy; 2012" />

    <title>takeover</title>

    <base href="" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="" />

    <style type="text/css" media="all" />

    #container {
         position:absolute;
         text-align:center;
         background-color:#fff;
         z-index:9999;
    }

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="takeover.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <p><a href="#">qwe</a></p>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
     window.onload = show;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 1**

Message that appears when using non-Internet Explorer browsers when placing `alert(show)` before `window.onload`

[image]

**EDIT 2**

The message displayed after removing all the white spaces. Again this only works in non-Internet Explorer browsers.

[image]

**EDIT 3**

Tried window.show = function show() and window.hide = function hide() however still get an error in Internet Explorer. The error is show as below.

[image]

**EDIT 4**

Here is the updated code with all the functions in a single file. This does not work in any other browser and I get the error `show` is undefined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict/EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtm1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-us" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <meta name="copyright" content="&copy; 2012" />

    <title>takeover</title>

    <base href="" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="" />

    <style type="text/css" media="all" />

    #container {
         position:absolute;
         text-align:center;
         background-color:#fff;
         z-index:9999;
    }

    </style>


</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <p><a href="#">qwe</a></p>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(show)
    window.show = function show() {
obj1 = document.getElementById("container").innerHTML =  '<div style="width: 960px; height: 2000px;"><p>Hello World.<br>Here I am.</p><p><a href="#" onclick="hide();">test</a></p></div>';
}

window.hide = function hide() { 
    obj1 = document.getElementById("container");
     if(obj1)
 {
   alert("Hi");
   obj1.style.display = "none";
   obj1.style.visibility = "hidden";
 }
 else
 {
   alert("Cannot find the element with id container.");
 }
}
     window.onload = window.show;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Derek - That doesn't make a difference either.

Comment: Why don't you try using window.onload = show; ...Then in the show() function, simply put an alert. Keep your original order of HTML and see what it does. Does it give an error or does an alert pop up?

Comment: There's no reason to declare functions as window.functionName.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line...

```
window.onload = show();
```

Should be this...

```
window.onload = show;
```

...because you need to assign the `show` function itself to `window.onload`, not its return value from calling it.

Comment: It was that before I place the closing brackets however I then get the error that `show` is not defined.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Then move the `window.onload` into the same `<script>` block as the `show` function, or at least move the `window.onload` script block before the `show` block.

Comment: @am not i am - That worked. Why is that? What difference does it make whether or not the script is in the same block or in an external file?

Comment: @emphaticsunshine - But is already defined. How else do I define it?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - It is not defined as it gets to `window.onload`.

Comment: @Derek - Can you elaborate further? Thanks

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: If the code is in the same script element, then the order won't matter because the function declaration takes place before any other code runs, irrespective of its position. In separate script elements, this isn't the case, so the script with the function needs to come before you use it.

Comment: [This works](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/GFLpF/1); [this does not work](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/GFLpF/).

Comment: @am not i am - Placing the script in the same block seems to break other functionality. I have posted the entire code base including the HTML.

Comment: @Derek: that's a little different. You didn't use a function declaration, so the order matters. OP's does have a function declaration, so the order wouldn't matter, except that they're in different scripts. http://jsfiddle.net/gG3ef/

Comment: @am not i am - I see. Looks like that's the only difference between `var a = function()` and `function a()`.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Are you sure the path to the script is correct? What happens if you do `alert(show)` just before the `window.onload`?

Comment: @am not i am - Yes it is. I tried the alert and I get the message in edit 1 however nothing happens in Internet Explorer.

Comment: @Derek: Yes, if the function is used as part of an expression, then the interpreter will not see it as a function declaration. To be a declaration, it can't be part of any type of operator. This is why people use `(function() {})()`. This coerces it out of its "declaration" so it can be immediately invoked.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: I don't see where `hide` is being called.

Comment: @am not i am - It is within the `show` function as part of the `<a>` element

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Try assigning show and hide directly to `window`, as in `window.show = function...` and `window.hide = function...`

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Your Edit 1 wasn't showing up for be before. There are some odd looking characters in that function. Delete it and retype it from scratch, or at least delete the white space. Also, make sure you're using a plain text editor.

Comment: @am not i am - Do you mean `window.show= function show() {
 obj1 = document.getElementById("container").innerHTML =  '<div style="width: 960px; height: 2000px;"><p>Hello World.<br>Here I am.</p>' +
         '<p><a href="#" onclick="hide();">test</a></p></div>'; 
}`

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Yes, that's what I meant, without the `<pre><code>` of course.

Comment: @am not i am - Updated the code and I removed all the white spaces in the code. I have updated the post with the alert I am shown. Also I am  using a plain text editor i.e. Notepad++

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Is that all your JavaScript code? Is your `hide` function nested inside another function?

Comment: @am not i am - I tried what you suggested with `window.show= function show()` however am still getting an error. Updated the question with a screenshot of what I see in Internet Explorer.

Comment: @am not i am - Yes. That is all the Javascript code. There is no other Javascript code.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: With the `window.show = function...`, you need to do it before the `window.onload = show`. Also try `window.onload = window.show`.

Comment: @am not i am - I placed both `window.show = function` and `window.hide = function` before `window.onload = show` and I get the alert in Internet Explorer but then the hide function doesn't work. Also after doing so it no longer works in any other browser i.e. I do not get the alert.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Then you have an error somewhere. If it doesn't work in any browser, then try it in Chrome, but make sure your browser's console is open so you can see any errors.

Comment: @am not i am - I did have a look at the browser's console when running Google Chrome and it says `show` is undefined. This occurred after I placed both `window.show = function` and `window.hide = function `before `window.onload = show`

Comment: You're not calling the functions with `()`, are you? You might as well update your question with the code at this point. Maybe clean it up a bit, removing some of the obsolete info.

Comment: @ am not i am - No. Will post the HTML code along with the Javascript code.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: You have `alert(show)` before the `window.show = func...` assignment. Remove that. It's breaking the script. Also remove `show` and `hide` from the function definitions, like: `window.show = function() {` instead of `window.show = function show() {`. This can cause odd issues in IE.

Comment: ...or you can change the functions back to `function show() {...}`. Either should now work.

Comment: @am not i am - That works now without errors in all browsers however the hide function breaks in Internet Explorer i.e. it doesn't hide the div element and rather redirects the users which is not the intended event.

Comment: `IE is the most frustrating thing I've ever dealt with.`

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Test the values in that function. `console.log(obj1)` `console.log(obj1.style)` Or use alerts if you prefer.

Comment: @am not i am - What alert can I use for Internet explorer?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: `alert(obj1)` `alert(obj1.style)`

Comment: ...sorry, going to have to break away.

Comment: @am not i am - I get the error that `obj1` is undefined in Internet Explorer as well as Google Chrome.

Comment: `add / show 36 more comments`... Maybe we should continue it in the chat?

Comment: @am not i am - This is one of the oddest things ever. It works when in Internet Explorer when I deploy it to a server but not locally. What gives?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Grabbing at straws here, but does it help if you remove the `<base>` element, or the `xmlns` stuff from the `<body>`? Also, if your script is in a separate file, maybe the local file isn't found. Beyond that, I'm just not sure.

Comment: @am not i am - I'll remove the `base` and XML namespace from the code to see if that make a difference. Does that mean I have to provide an absolute path to the javascript file i.e. `file:///`?

Comment: @am not i am - Your point about the file not being found was valid. That was a trip in circles. Menacing Internet Explorer. The only issue is that the hide function still redirects me rather than hiding the container.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: There shouldn't be a redirect because of the `href="#"`, but you can add `return false;` to the function to prevent the default link behavior.

Comment: @am not i am - I did that to the end of the hide function but it still redirects. Am I doing it incorrectly?

`function hide() { 
 obj1 = document.getElementById("container");
  if(obj1)
 {
   alert("Hi");
   obj1.style.display = "none";
   obj1.style.visibility = "hidden";
 }
 else
 {
   alert("Cannot find the element with id container.");
 }
 return false;
}`

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: I forgot it was inline. Keep the `return false;` as it is in the `hide` function, but change your inline handler to `onclick="return hide();"`. This will return the `false` value that is returned from `hide`. Or you could do it all inline: `onclick="hide(); return false;"` though I prefer the first way.

Comment: @am not i am - Awesome! That finally worked. If I could up vote you like a gazillion times I would. Thanks an infinite loop. Oh yeah. Thanks for sticking by the post and comments.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `<script>` block that references `container` to a point *after* `container` is defined:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <DIV id="container"></DIV>
<script type="text/javascript">
     window.onload = show;

    function show() {
        obj1 = document.getElementById("container").innerHTML =  '<div style="width: 960px; height: 2000px;"><p>Hello World.<br>Here I am.</p>' +
                                 '<p><a href="#" onclick="hide();">test</a></p></div>';

}
</script>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

---

If the `<script>` block is, for example, inside the `<head>` then Internet Explorer gives the error:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to set value of the property 'innerHTML': object is null or undefined

on page load.

Comment: If the function is assigned to `window.onload` then it will run after the page is loaded, so it's OK to put it in the head.